# how to base64 encode an unsigned byte array which is actually a int[]

Tags: java, c#, base64, arrays, sha1

I have a problem to communicating between **C#** and **JAVA**. I have to hash a value in my program with **SHA1** in **JAVA**. The problem is, computing hash in **JAVA** results a `byte[]` (so do **C#**, but:) `byte` type in **JAVA** is *signed*, while it's *unsigned* in **C#**. So I have to get rid of extra bits in **JAVA** (the **C#** side can not be touched). Here is what I'm doing:

```
private static int[] Hash(byte[] plainBytes, byte[] saltBytes)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] sourceBytes = new byte[plainBytes.length + saltBytes.length];
    for (int i = 0, il = plainBytes.length; i < il; i++)
        sourceBytes[i] = plainBytes[i];
    for (int i = 0, il = saltBytes.length, pil = plainBytes.length; i < il; i++)
        sourceBytes[pil + i] = saltBytes[i];
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    digest.reset();
    byte[] resultBytes = digest.digest(sourceBytes);
    int[] result = new int[resultBytes.length];
    for (int i = 0, il = resultBytes.length; i < il; i++)
        result[i] = ((int) resultBytes[i]) & 255;
    return result;
}
```

It gives me the correct array. But, the problem is *base64* encoding the `result`. How can I do that without falling in `signed byte` trap again? I mean how to complete this snippet:

```
var resultArray = Hash(someSource, someSalt);
var resultBase64EncodedString = HOW_TO_BASE64_ENCODE_HERE(resultArray);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean that `byte` is unsigned in C# and signed in Java?

Comment: Yep :) correcting question

Comment: Byte value 0xff is `-1` in java and `255` in C#.  But it is only integer representation.  There are no difference in internal representaion. 0xff is 0xff.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding your resultBytes array with

```
String base64EncodedString = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(resultBytes);
```

should give you the same base64 coded string as you get in C# with

```
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];
currentHash = sha1.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
String base64EncodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(currentHash);
```